# loading javascript in a div on <a tag click

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am practicing on java script,

i have 3 "a" tags and one div in my page.I want to load different java script file(which is for loading google map) in div on each "a" click, 
this is my html page

```
<body>
<li><a href="#" >india</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >bangladesh</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >UAE</a></li>


<div id="loader"></div>
```

how can i load different javascript on each "a" click without page refresh

Comment: Javascript does not refresh page. What have you tried? Share some actual code.

Comment: I think in this case, instead of loading different JavaScript file to load different map, you should use single file which will load different map by checking which link was clicked.

Comment: javascript files need all to be loaded, and each `a` tag click will show its map or something else and hide 2 other.

Comment: @JaredChu  so how can we make change only in a single div on each "a" click??

Comment: you should use single file which will load different map wrap into function . and call function one by one using link

Comment: @unknownprogrammer use `javascript` or `jQuery`, please post full example code in `https://jsfiddle.net/` so we can help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/axdcy1w9/  try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Try the below code Hope you are looking for this

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var latLng = jQuery(this).attr("data-latLng");          
    initialize(latLng);
    });

    function initialize(latLng) {
    latLng = latLng.split(",")
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[0],latLng[1]),
        zoom: 8
     };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map- 
    canvas"),  mapOptions);
     }
     });
```

and the html

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="20.593684,78.962880">India</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="23.684994,   
90.356331">Bangladesh</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="23.424076,53.847818">UAE</a>
```

**see the below Fiddle below For Details**

[Div map Load Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJdtY/150/)

Comment: exactly this is what i wanted, but i want to add markers also, where can i add them?

Answer (score 0):

use [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/) and add data attribute of latitude and longitude of your place like below

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-Latitude="22.5773626" data-Longitude="79.5222058">india</a>
```

then on your jquery side write this script

```
  $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
      var latitude = $(this).attr("data-Latitude");
      var longitude = $(this).attr("data-Longitude");
      $('#loader').gmap3('destroy');
      $('#loader')
          .gmap3({
           center:[latitude , longitude ],
           zoom:4
       })
       .marker([{position:[latitude , longitude ]}                
      ])      
    });
```